# How can add email signature in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have a codeigniter function to send emails.Its working fine,but the only problem is email signature id not adding to my email. I am using gmail to send email. i set email signature in gmail configuration.

**How can add email signature in codeigniter**?

Comment: have you google it before posting on SO?

Comment: i spend 3 hour in google

Comment: you mean like in the end of the mail Regards, Messi Fan

Comment: yes. with some declaimer text

Answer (score 1):

You can use views for this

```
    // views/email_message.php
    <?php echo $this->load->view('email/message', $message_data(), TRUE) ?>
    <?php echo $this->load->view('email/signature', $signature_data(), TRUE) ?>
```

and then you can pass this to your email message:

```
// in your controller
$message = $this->load->view('views/email_message', $data(), TRUE);

// configure email options, etc.
...
$this->email->message($message);

// send the email
```